# How can I create a non-ssh VPN on debian/linux?

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, remote-access

I have a set of remote servers, assigned to a small IP address pool. I would like to control access to some services on some servers via ip address, rather than login/password.

However, I would like to access these services from wifi hotspots, etc, so I would like to create a VPN which I would log in to (via a username/password), which would be assigned one of the IP addresses in the server's pool.

I would like to use built in clients on Windows and Mac OS X to access the VPN, which I believe rules out the commonly advocated ssh solutions.

What packages should I look into and configure on debian/linux to achieve this setup?

Comment: I am a bit curious about why you are ruling out SSH?

Comment: For the stated reason - I want to know what my options are to use the built in clients. I will probably give access to this VPN to people who I can't insist install particular software on their PCs

Comment: I should perhaps observe that I have looked at OpenVPN, and it is obviously a good solution to many VPN problems. Just not the one I wish to solve in this question.

Comment: @John: personally I believe that the ease and flexibility of OpenVPN outweighs the hassles that IPSec or similar solutions have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

xl2tpd is in Debian. It's a server for L2TP IPSec VPN. Windows supports L2TP natively. Alternatively, you can use OpenSwan (also in Debian) to set up IPSec.

I know you want to focus on built-in clients, but take a look at OpenVPN just the same. It's cross-platform and easy to set up and deploy. It's also extremely secure and flexible at the same time. I tried to set up xl2tpd and went with OpenVPN instead.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Poptop](http://poptop.sourceforge.net) will do the job for you. If you look in Debians package management tool you should see it.

Apparently works for Windows and Mac OS X clients (>= 10.2) although as this [this](http://4sysops.com/archives/poptop-linux-vpn-server-for-windows-clients-using-pptp/) article points out, you might be compromising your network security using it.

Answer (score 3):

What services are you providing?  If the services support it, you should simply consider enabling SSL, or adding SSL via something like [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/).

[OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) is one of the best packages you could install in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

'Built in clients' is your limiting factor here.  You likely need a PPTP or IPSec solution.